# writing a documentation : regex matches pattern, the other way around, or both?

Tags: regex

I'm writing a document for a software that has heavy use of regex. Which of the following expressions are acceptable, regarding the use of the word *match*?

- The *regex* `a.` *matches the string* `aa`.
- The *string* `aa` *matches the regex* `a.`.
- This function lists all the strings *matched by* the regex.
- This function lists all the strings *matched with* the regex.
- This function lists all the strings *matching* the regex.

I've seen many usages of *[regex] matches [string]*. Are others acceptable?

This question probably belongs to [English.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [English language learners](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but I thought this was a bit too technical and decided to ask here. Anyway, I believe this can be considered as [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think regex = pattern. It should be "The regex `a.` matches the string `aa`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely "regex matches the string". This usage is also consistent with the excellent book *Mastering Regular Expressions* by Jeffrey Friedl. You can take a peek at the book on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) to see some examples.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the pointer to the book! Any insights into the passive voice, additionally?

Comment: Well, the use of passive voice is generally discouraged so I would recommend using "regex matches a string" rather than "string is matched by a regex".

Comment: OK, so "This function lists all the strings that the regex matches" is the better choice. Thanks again!